Was there any mention of metal helmets in ancient India?
Primarily during the reign of the Guptas is their any mention of use of metal helmets and even armour if so how did these look like?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

Historium dates bronze helmets in India to circa 2100 BCE. Wikipedia discusses armor in the Mauryan period, and in the Gupta period, although the latter is ... not up to the quality standard I'd like. Reddit discusses lamellar armor, which would strongly suggest metal helmets.

@MCW what about in terms of looks

I couldn't find anything I found credible/reliable. If I were to take it further, I'd do a Google image search on "Gupta Armor" and then check the images for sources, credibility,etc.

Most had turbans on temple wall drawings.

Recommend you edit your comments into the question.  Comments by OP diminish the probability and quality of an answer.
